# Python: how to bitmask and compare mac address?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.

The following line of code extract dst mac and src mac from a Ethernet packet.

```
dst, src, _eth_type = struct.unpack_from('!6s6sH', buffer(msg.data), 0)
```

As we know, mac address is of 6-byte. What I want to archive is to compare if the first 5 bytes of dst/src mac addresses equal. How to write python code for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation) to extract subsequences from sequences like lists or strings. Comparing the first five bytes/characters of your `dst` and `src` strings is trivial:

```
dst[:5] == src[:5]
```